# Multiple Correct If Statements from a Mouse Click Event

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to do waste collection program and these are part of codes. My problem is if the picturebox shows image that on second if statements (magazine), there is no problem. But if shows first image that on first if statements (newspaper) and if NewWaste(); gives magazine then there is a problem. Because it adds both of them to listbox but I don't see the second image on picturebox. How can I solve that?

```
private void NewWaste()
        {
            Image[] images = new Image[] { newspaper.Image, magazine.Image, glass.Image };
            int wastes = rnd.Next(images.Length);
            wastePictureBox.Image = images[wastes];
    }
            //(part of class)
            public bool Add(Waste waste)
            {
                if (FilledVolume + waste.Volume <= Capacity)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }

private void addPaperWasteBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (paperWasteBox.Add(newspaper) == true && wastePictureBox.Image == newspaper.Image)
            {
                paperWasteListBox.Items.Add("Newspaper");
                NewWasteImage();
            }
            if (paperWasteBox.Add(magazine) == true && wastePictureBox.Image == magazine.Image)
            {
                paperAtikListBox.Items.Add("Magazine");
                NewWasteImage();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What does `NewWasteImage();` do?

Comment: Sorry, I mean NewWaste();

Comment: OT for that Add method, a better name would be CanAdd. "Add" suggest that it adds a Waste somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the second `if` statement to run if the first one didn't, then you want an `else if` statement before the second conditional check.

Change:

```
        if (paperWasteBox.Add(newspaper) == true && wastePictureBox.Image == newspaper.Image)
        {
            paperWasteListBox.Items.Add("Newspaper");
            NewWasteImage();
        }
        if (paperWasteBox.Add(magazine) == true && wastePictureBox.Image == magazine.Image)
        {
            paperAtikListBox.Items.Add("Magazine");
            NewWasteImage();
        }
```

To:

```
        if (paperWasteBox.Add(newspaper) == true && wastePictureBox.Image == newspaper.Image)
        {
            paperWasteListBox.Items.Add("Newspaper");
            NewWasteImage();
        }
        else if (paperWasteBox.Add(magazine) == true && wastePictureBox.Image == magazine.Image)
        {
            paperAtikListBox.Items.Add("Magazine");
            NewWasteImage();
        }
```

Notice the difference in the SIXTH line!

Comment: It was actually very simple but I could not think. Thank you so much.